# How to convert bson::Bson to Vec<u8> in rust?

Tags: rust, bson

I am trying to get a byte array of a `non-document` bson object value:

When attempting this:

```
let value: bson::Bson = bson::Bson::String(String::from("heya"));
bson::to_vec(&value).unwrap();
```

Then this error is produced:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: SerializationError { message: "attempted to encode a non-document type at the top level: String" }', ****\src\**\mod.rs:83:43
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

... I don't have a document and the documentation is un-clear that this can't be done and isn't clear as to how to achieve this.

Comment: What is the `value` in your code example?

Comment: It's pulled from the document itself so it could be of any type.

Comment: ```for key in working_document.keys() { let value = working_document.get(key.as_str()).unwrap(); }```

Comment: What is the actual value that causes the error you showed?

Comment: ```let value: bson::Bson = bson::Bson::String(String::from("heya"));
bson::to_vec(&value).unwrap();```

Comment: @drewtato it also doesn't matter as this happens with any value ... simply put ... I am trying to get the bson representation of a field and it doesn't work as expected so I thought that maybe there's a different method I need to use?

Comment: Like the error message says: “attempted to encode a non-document type at the top level: String”

Comment: What do you want the returned `Vec<u8>` to contain? Just the bytes of the string (or whatever other `bson` type it may be)? Or a full `bson` serialized document containing the string?

Comment: @AndersEvensen Yep - it's really as simple as that ... given a Bson, just return the bytes of its value (or an empty vec if nothing is there).

Comment: Sorry for not expanding on that comment, I thought you deleted your question. The point is that the root of BSON is a document (https://bsonspec.org/spec.html), so if you have a non-document, are you looking for the `element` part of the linked spec (e.g. an empty string would be serialized as `02 00 00 00 00 00`), or…? Or alternatively, to answer a lot of potential clarifying questions, what are you going to use it for (e.g. will your own code be deserializing the bytes later)?

Comment: @Ry- For this I am simply trying to retrieve the byte equivalent of the value stored - it will be used as an 'index' in what is equivalent of a B-Tree for optimizing record lookups. As it stands right now - what might need to happen is to manually pull out the actual values for each supported variant type and acquire their bytes directly. bincode sort-of works but isn't quite what I am looking for here.

Comment: What's the issue with bincode? Or just using `Hash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Outside of a document, it isn't obvious what serializing a string as BSON should mean. Ordinarily, BSON would store the following data in order:

- Type
- Key + `\0`
- Length
- String + `\0`

So if you want just the value, it's the string itself. If you want the value plus the null terminator, it's the previous part plus the null byte. If you want the length, value, and null terminator, then it's the length (including null byte), then all the previous parts. You can see this in `bson` [here](https://docs.rs/bson/2.6.1/src/bson/ser/mod.rs.html#44-49). None of these are valid BSON since they are not contained within a document, and don't even include the key or type, so their utility is limited.

The `bson` crate doesn't expose this functionality, so you'll have to copy/write it in your own code. However, they are quite simple.

If you are trying to get something that's valid BSON, you could put it in a simple document:

```rs
bson::doc! { "0": value }
```

Comment: It's not a terrible idea and might be better for composite indexes